# JavaFX TableView not updating

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

JavaFX TableView does not update when calling `table.getItems().setAll(lst);` where `List<Student> lst;` even though on another project this logic seems to work.

So, I have an object Student with getters.

```
public class Student implements HasID<Integer> {
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String group;
private String email;
private String guide;


public Student(int _id, String _name, String _group, String _email, String _guide) {
    this.id = _id;
    this.name = _name;
    this.group = _group;
    this.email = _email;
    this.guide = _guide;
}

@Override
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String getGroup() {
    return this.group;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public String getGuide() {
    return this.guide;
}
```

I have the fxml for the table.

```
<TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="113.0" prefHeight="397.0" prefWidth="480.0">
    <columns>
      <TableColumn fx:id="id" prefWidth="61.0" text="ID" />
      <TableColumn fx:id="name" prefWidth="119.0" text="Name" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="group" prefWidth="78.0" text="Group" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="email" prefWidth="102.0" text="Email" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="guide" prefWidth="119.0" text="Guide" />
    </columns>
  </TableView>
```

And in the end, I have the method of the controller to populate the table.

```
public void testAction() {
    List<Student> lst = s.findAllListStudent();

    table.getItems().setAll(lst);

    for (Student x : lst) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

The controller and the method are linked properly because I can see the output of `println` and I can see a change in the table, yet no data is shown.
Example (before and after triggering the method):

[image: Before pressing the button to trigger the method]
[image: After]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are your cell value factories?

Comment: You're absolutely right... I totally forgot about them... fully.
Sorry to have asked such a question, it totally slipped my mind and I was looking through what might have I done wrong for 1 hour straight. Thanks a bunch for the point.

Comment: @James_D You can post it as an answer, edited and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TableView` has

1. A [collection of `TableColumn`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getColumns--), and
2. A [collection of `item`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getItems--), with each item representing the value displayed in a row in the table.

In order for a column to display values in each of the cells in that column, the column needs a function mapping the value for the row to the value to be displayed in the corresponding cell. Specifically, if you have a `TableView<S>`, then the value for each row is represented by an object of type `S`. Each column is a `TableColumn<S,T>`, and the function mapping a row to a value to be displayed in the corresponding cell in that column is a `Callback<CellDataFeatures<S,T>, ObservableValue<T>>`. (`CellDataFeatures` is just a wrapper for the row value.) This function is called the `cellValueFactory` for the column (it is a function creating the value to be displayed in the cell).

So you need to supply cell value factories for each of your columns. In your controller's `initialize()` method, do something like:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Student, Number> id ;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Student, String> name ;

public void initialize() {
    id.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(cellData.getValue().getId()));
    name.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getName()));
    // ...
}
```

and similarly for the remaining columns.